# "The boy was very sad when his toy fell on the ground" - is "sad" a subject complement?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is "sad" a subject complement and "when his toy fell on the ground" - an adverbial? Do I understand it right that semantically "the boy" is Agent?

Comment: I don't think "agent" is valid for your example. In something like *"The boy kicked the ball"*, *the boy* is the "agent", *the ball* is the "patient", but this is more a *linguistic* categorisation system than one you'll encounter in traditional *grammar*.

Comment: No, it's not a subject complement; a subject complement is a clause. _Sad_ is the predicate. And since it's an adjective, it's a predicate adjective. The adverbial clause beginning with _while_ is indeed an adverbial. As for the role of the subject NP, it's "experiencer", since the predicate is an emotion.

Comment: @JohnLawler http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement from what I know, a subject complement is not always a clause

Comment: Sorry, Wikipedia got it wrong, as often happens with crowd-sourced grammar rules. "Subject complement" is not a term in use by grammarians or linguists to refer to predicate adjectives. For "subject complements" in actual use, see [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html) or [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf). For predicates, including predicate nouns and predicate adjectives, see [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It is a predicate adjective. See [wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Predicative_adjective)

> Predicative adjectives are linked via a copula or other linking
>   mechanism to the noun or pronoun they modify; for example, happy is a
>   predicate adjective in "they are happy" and in "that made me happy."

The term "adjective complement" is also sometimes used to refer to predicate adjectives. See [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/objects.htm).